# How to separate values in array by comma with Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to get filter values in array, separated by comma in Apps Script. To illustrate, here is my function:

```
function filterReport(){
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName('DATA');
 var emailds = getColumnNrByName(dataSheet, 'Email');
 var emailFilters = dataSheet.getRange(2, emailds, dataSheet.getLastRow() -1).getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < emailFilters.length; i++) {

    var payload = JSON.stringify({
    'reportMetadata': {
    'reportFilters': [{  
      'value' : emailFilters[i][0],
      'column': 'EMAIL',
      'operator': 'equals' 
   }]
   }
    });

      Logger.log(payload)

}
 }
```

This is what I get:

```
[16-08-09 10:54:34:612 PDT] {"reportMetadata":{"reportFilters":[{"value”:”email1@test.com","column":"EMAIL","operator":"equals"}]}}
[16-08-09 10:54:34:613 PDT] {"reportMetadata":{"reportFilters":[{"value":"email2@test.com","column":"EMAIL","operator":"equals"}]}}
[16-08-09 10:54:34:613 PDT] {"reportMetadata":{"reportFilters":[{"value":"email3@test.com","column":"EMAIL","operator":"equals"}]}}
[16-08-09 10:54:34:614 PDT] {"reportMetadata":{"reportFilters":[{"value":"email4@test.com","column":"EMAIL","operator":"equals"}]}}
```

And I need:

```
{"reportMetadata":{"reportFilters":[{"value”:”email1@test.com, email2@test.com, email3@test.com, email4@test.com","column":"EMAIL","operator":"equals"}]}}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you already tried to use the split command ?
By using this command you can turn a string into an array.

You can take a look at this link for mode details:

[String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: Closer! if I run var `array = emailFilters.toString().split(",");` I get `{"reportMetadata":{"reportFilters":[{"value”:[”email1@test.com, email2@test.com, email3@test.com, email4@test.com”],”column":"EMAIL","operator":"equals"}]}}`. How do I remove '[ ]' after value?

Comment: `var array = emailFilters.toString().split(",").join();` worked

Comment: I do recommend take a look at the website cited below. Actually you're dealing with json object and I think will be pretty interesting dig a little bit deeper about this subject.
http://www.json.org/js.html

Answer (score 0):

I used Cordeiro split with an array of emails from a sheet and it worked well.

I took a column of emails as an array and then use the split:

```
//Array
var EMAILS = emss.getRange(["C3:"+"C"+em_wlr]).getDisplayValues();
//Split
var emails_cs = EMAILS.toString().split(",").join();
```

Then I can use in the MailApp:

```
MailApp.sendEmail(emails_cs, templateSubject, templateText);
```